# Write a twitter login Handler class

Tags: java, android

My Question is how can I write a twitter login handler that should contain a method called login and it should do all task regarding login.
in our activity on sign in with twitter button click handler i just want to create twitter login handler object and invoke login method .so that it can be reusable to any android app please have your answer here .

thanks everyone ...@@

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to authenticate a user is using TwitterLoginButton.
Inside your layout, add a Login button with the following code:

```
<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
     android:id="@+id/login_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Configure the button in an Activity**

```
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton;
...

loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
   @Override
   public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
       // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
   }

   @Override
   public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
       // Do something on failure
   }
});
```

**Pass the Activity’s result back to the button**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result to the login button.
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Inside the Activity hosting the Fragment, pass the result from the Activity to the Fragment.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result to the fragment, which will then pass the result to the login
    // button.
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

TwitterSession

If logIn completes successfully, a TwitterSession is provided in the success result. This TwitterSession will contain a token, secret, username, and user ID of the user and becomes the active session and is automatically persisted. If you need to retrieve the TwitterSession at a later time, you may do so using the SessionManager.

```
TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
String token = authToken.token;
String secret = authToken.secret;
```

Comment: I dont have to do with sdk

Comment: Abdul I have to make a separate Java class in which login features must be available and we would be able to invoke from button click listener with an object of that class to invoke login() method.